# How to resize image scan to text content?

Tags: shell-script, image-manipulation

I make a script witch scan papers and send it by mail.

But in some cases there is a lot of blanc space in the scaned image and I would like to automatically resize image to content.

So, for example, with the following document:

[image: main.png]

I want that my script resize it automatically to detected content, like this:

[image: main-preresizing.png]

To finally only get a file witch is like this:

[image: resized.png]

So, there is some cli application or way witch work like `resizetocontent <inputfile> <outputfile>`, as I described it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim)'s autocrop:

```
 convert -trim main.png trimmed.png
```

Comment: It work with graphic images (Images I produce using Inkscape or LaTeX) with real #FFFFFF white parts. But it doesn’t work with documents I scan and witch contain some impurity.

Comment: It works, if you scroll down the manpage and read _fuzzy color selection_ instead of me.

Comment: I finally find it, I had to use `trim 70%`.